# "React Module Not Found Error: Upgraded to Latest react-dom, Checked File Paths, Cleared Cache, Still Facing Issue"

Tags: reactjs, node.js

i guys i'm new in react i have this problem where i'm trying to import the MeetupList.js component in my AllMeetups.js component and i already exported MeetupList component.
My file Structure is like this

```
src
|-- components
|   |-- meetups
|   |   |-- MeetupList.js
|   |   |-- MeetupItem.js
|-- pages
|   |-- AllMeetups.js
```

This is my import in AllMeetups.js file
"import MeetupList from '../components/meetups/MeetupList.js' "

This is the error i got in the browser .
Compiled with problems:
ERROR in ./src/components/pages/AllMeetups.js 4:0-61
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
'../components/meetups/MeetupList.js' in '/home/zoren/my-react-app/src/components/pages'

AllMeetup.js

```
import MeetupList from "../components/meetups/MeetupList";
import classes from "./AllMeetups.module.css";


const DUMMY_DATA = [
  {
    id: "m1",
    title: "This is a first meetup",
    image:
      "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d3/Stadtbild_M%C3%BCnchen.jpg/2560px-Stadtbild_M%C3%BCnchen.jpg",
    address: "Meetup street 5, 12345 Meetup City",
    description:
      "This is a first, amazing meetup which you definitely should not miss. It will be a lot of fun!",
  },
  {
    id: "m2",
    title: "This is a second meetup",
    image:
      "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d3/Stadtbild_M%C3%BCnchen.jpg/2560px-Stadtbild_M%C3%BCnchen.jpg",
    address: "Meetup street 5, 12345 Meetup City",
    description:
      "This is a first, amazing meetup which you definitely should not miss. It will be a lot of fun!",
  },
];

function AllMeetupsPage() {
  return (
    <section className={classes.header}>
      <h1> All Meetups</h1>
      <MeetupList meetups= {DUMMY_DATA} />
    </section>
  );
}

export default AllMeetupsPage;
```

MeetupList.js

```
import MeetupItem from "./meetups/MeetupItem";
import classes from "./MeetupList.module.css";

function MeetupList(props) {
  return (
    <ul className={classes.list}>
      {props.meetups.map((meetup) => (
        <MeetupItem
          key={meetup.id}
          id={meetup.id}
          image={meetup.image}
          title={meetup.title}
          address={meetup.address}
          description={meetup.description}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

export default MeetupList;
```

MeetupItem.js

```
import classes from "./MeetupItem.module.css";

function MeetupItem(props) {
  return (
    <li className={classes.item}>
      <div className={classes.image}>
        <img src={props.img} alt={props.title} />
      </div>
      <div className={classes.content}>
        <h3> TITLE</h3>
        <address>{props.title}</address>
        <p> {props.description}</p>
      </div>
      <div className={classes.actions}>
        <button> To Favorites </button>
      </div>
    </li>
  );
}
export default MeetupItem;
```

These are the things i already tried .
Update Dependencies:

- Updated react-dom and NPM to the latest versions.
- Verify Pathing:
- 
- Confirmed correct file pathing.
- File Recreate:
- 
- Deleted and recreated the file with the same name.
- Restart Server:
- 
- Restarted the development server.
- Check for Typos:
- 
- Ensured no typos or syntax errors in import statements.
- Clear Cache:
- 
- Cleared npm cache.
- Reinstall Dependencies:
- 
- Removed node_modules and reinstalled dependencies.
- Additional Checks:
- 
- Ensured no circular dependencies, verified Node.js and NPM versions, and reviewed package.json for correctness.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The path relative to a file inside `components/pages` would have to be `../../components/meetup/MeetupList` or just `./meetup/MeetupList`, as `..` would be the components directory itself so `../components` as you have it now would be `components/components` which clearly does not exist.